# Pause between keyframe animations

Tags: animation, css

got an simple animation with keyframes.

```css
    @-webkit-keyframes rotation {
    0%   { -webkit-transform: rotate(10deg); }
    25%  { -webkit-transform: rotate(5deg); }
    50%  { -webkit-transform: rotate(10deg); }
    75%   { -webkit-transform: rotate(5deg); }
    100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(10deg); }

}
```

and

```css
.class { -webkit-animation: rotation 1s infinite; }
```

Is it possible to add a pause between this keyframe animation? Like 5 seconds?
I know there is a *-webkit-animation-delay* but this delays only the start of the animation.

P.S. I know its only the webkit prefix... at the end I get it through prefixr.

Comment: Check out this tutorial it has demos and goes over each style and class http://www.leemunroe.com/css3-animations/

Comment: why not just remove .class ? (if the class is only the animation)

Comment: @denny_mueller I was thinking of the same solution as your edit. Why don't you provide that as your own answer and mark it accepted?

Comment: Thanks for mentioning `animation-delay`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Got an workaround, but looks bit dirty

```
@-webkit-keyframes rotation {
        0%   { -webkit-transform: rotate(10deg); }
        5%  { -webkit-transform: rotate(5deg); }
        10%  { -webkit-transform: rotate(10deg); }
        15%   { -webkit-transform: rotate(5deg); }
        20% { -webkit-transform: rotate(10deg); }
        100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(10deg); }

    }
.class { -webkit-animation: rotation 5s infinite; }
```

Answer (score 12):

After struggling with this problem myself and the help of Denny Mueller I've found that the key is to stop before 100%.

You can use the delay to start with a delay and after the first iteration, the delay will be the amount of time that is left after the animation is finished.

Here is what I used for my implementation:

```
@-webkit-keyframes spincube {
    from,to      {                                                    }
    8%,14%       { -webkit-transform: rotateY(-90deg);                }
    24%,30%      { -webkit-transform: rotateY(-90deg) rotateZ(90deg); }
    40%,46%      { -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg) rotateZ(90deg); }
    56%,62%      { -webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg) rotateX(90deg);  }
    72%,78%      { -webkit-transform: rotateX(90deg);                 }
    88%,94%      { -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg);                  }
}
```

As you can see, I stop at 94% and the remaining 6% is used to pause on the first frame.

Answer (score 0):

the other answers do the trick. but for those who use Mui makeStyles:

```
import React from 'react';
import { useStyles } from './useStyles';

export const BouncingDots = () => {
  const styles = useStyles();

  return (
    <div className={styles.root}>
      <div className={styles.dot} />
      <div className={styles.dot} />
      <div className={styles.dot} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

```
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import { COLORS } from 'src/data/ui';

export const useStyles = makeStyles(
  () => ({
    root: {
      display: 'flex',
      justifyContent: 'center',
      gap: 3,
    },

    dot: {
      width: 5,
      height: 5,
      borderRadius: '50%',
      backgroundColor: COLORS.primary.default,
      animation: '$bounce 1s infinite alternate',

      '&:nth-child(2)': {
        animationDelay: '0.2s',
      },
      '&:nth-child(3)': {
        animationDelay: '0.3s',
      },
    },

    '@keyframes bounce': {
      '0%': {
        opacity: 1,
        transform: 'translateY(0px)',
      },

      //this is a hack to make the dots pause for half of the time
      '50%': {
        opacity: 0.5,
        transform: 'translateY(-4px)',
      },

      '100%': {
        opacity: 0.5,
        transform: 'translateY(-4px)',
      },
    },
  }),
  { name: 'Suggestions' }
);
```