# Pause and resume a CSS3 background animation with a button?

Tags: css, animation

I want to add a button that can pause/resume the animation preferably using `JS`.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/469Nw/) is what I've got so far.

I just need a button that can pause/resume the animation. I've looked all over the stackoverflow forums but I am not able to find appropriate solution for this.

EDIT: Preferably JavaScript

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pause between keyframe animations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11689802/pause-between-keyframe-animations)

Comment: It can be dopne with pure css3 too, and it were the main extension of css3 next to css2... if you want solve this with js, you hadn't to mention css3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create a class to pause it and use jQuery toggleClass like this

```
$('.btn').click(function(e){
    $('body').toggleClass('paused');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/469Nw/3/

Answer (score 2):

You can use [animation-play-state](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-play-state) for that and use something like this:

```
var counter = 1;
$('button').on('click', function(){
if(counter){
    $('body').css({'-webkit-animation-play-state': 'paused',
                   'animation-play-state': 'paused'});
counter = 0;
} else{
    $('body').css({'-webkit-animation-play-state': 'running',
                   'animation-play-state': 'running'});
}
});
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/469Nw/4/)

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
var paused = false;
$(".btn").click(function () {
    document.body.style.animationPlayState = paused ? "running" : "paused";
    paused = !paused;
})
```

also you might need this reference [link](http://css-tricks.com/controlling-css-animations-transitions-javascript/) and the modified [example](http://jsfiddle.net/QjgJ2/)