# Pausing a css3 keyframe animation

Tags: css, animation, internet-explorer-9, keyframe

I have two patterns. I would like show them in this order

1) fade in pattern 1
2) fade in pattern 2
3) fade out pattern 1
4) fade out pattern 2

and then repeat indefinitely.

I have this, which shows the correct order, but does not pause the pattern, while the other fades in.

```
@keyframes fadeIn {
  0%   { opacity: 0; }
  100% { opacity: 1; }
 }

@keyframes fadeOut {
 0%   { opacity: 1; }
 100% { opacity: 0; }
}


.pattern-one  {
  animation: fadeIn 2s infinite alternate;
}

.pattern-two  {
  animation: fadeOut 2s infinite alternate;
}
```

Is it possible to introduce a pause?

Comment: Yes, check out [animation-play-state](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-play-state)

Comment: Also this question has a workaround if you need browser support beyond what `animation-play-state` works in: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11689802/pause-between-keyframe-animations

Comment: I do need IE9 support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

are you trying to achieve something like this?

```css
@keyframes fadeIn {
  0%   { opacity: 1; }
  25% { opacity: 0; }
  50% { opacity: 1; }
  75% { opacity: 1; }
  100% { opacity: 1; }
 }

@keyframes fadeOut {
  0%   { opacity: 1; }
  25% { opacity: 1; }
  50% { opacity: 0; }
  75% { opacity: 1; }
  100% { opacity: 1; }
}


.pattern-one  {
  animation: fadeIn 4s infinite;
}

.pattern-two  {
  animation: fadeOut 4s infinite;
}
div{
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  background-color: blue;
  margin:10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="pattern-one"></div>
<div class="pattern-two"></div>
```

Comment: very close, but there should be no point where both patterns are not visible

Comment: edited little bit, for more desired timing try play with percents and values. NOTE: animation must have opacity value at 0% same as at 100% for ease